# R - Exctracting a vector of doubles from data.frame

Tags: r, class, dataframe, double, character

I got this question using `read.table()` with or without `header=T`, trying to extract a vector of doubles from the resulting `data.frame` with `as.double(as.character())` (see `?factor`).

But that's just *how* I realized that I don't understand R's logic. So you won't see e.g. `read.table` in the code below, only the necessary parts. Could you tell me what's the difference between the following options?

1. With `header=T` equivalent:

   ```
   (a <- data.frame(array(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), c(1,4))))
   as.character(a)
   # [1] "0.5" "0.5" "0.5" "0.5"
   ```
2. Without `header=T` equivalent:

   ```
   b <- data.frame(array(c("a",0.5,"b",0.5,"c",0.5,"d",0.5), c(2,4)))
   (a <- b[2,])
   as.character(a)
   # [1] "1" "1" "1" "1"

   (a <- data.frame(a, row.names=NULL)) # now there's not even a visual difference
   as.character(a)
   # [1] "1" "1" "1" "1"
   ```

Comment: You're dealing with `factor`s. Add a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` into your `data.frame` steps and compare.

Comment: The `stringsAsFactors` conversion when using `read.table` and variants is a common source of confusion.  As always, using `str` on your data to understand exactly what you are working with can be very valuable.  Once you are aware of the `stringsAsFactors` argument, it becomes a very useful tool.  You can also set the option globally if you choose with `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I will read up on factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the default setting of `data.frame`, where one of the options, `stringsAsFactors` is set to `TRUE`. This is a problem in your scenario because when you use `header = FALSE`, the presence of character values in that row coerces the entire column to characters, which is then converted to factors (unless you set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`).

Here are some examples to play with:

```
## Two similar `data.frame`s -- just one argument different

b <- data.frame(array(c("a",0.5,"b",0.5,"c",0.5,"d",0.5), c(2,4)))
b2 <- data.frame(array(c("a",0.5,"b",0.5,"c",0.5,"d",0.5), c(2,4)),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## First with "b"

as.character(b[2, ])
# [1] "1" "1" "1" "1"

sapply(b[2, ], as.character)
#    X1    X2    X3    X4 
# "0.5" "0.5" "0.5" "0.5"
as.matrix(b)[2, ]
#    X1    X2    X3    X4 
# "0.5" "0.5" "0.5" "0.5"
as.double(as.matrix(b)[2, ])
# [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5

## Now with "b2"

as.character(b2[2, ])
# [1] "0.5" "0.5" "0.5" "0.5"
as.double(as.character(b2[2, ]))
# [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now see in `?read.table` / `colClasses` this assumption (mentioned in passing) that it is the *columns* of the data which are supposed to be of the same class. Is there a way to change this to the rows? You know I doubt it, but it could be interesting. (And is there a good help for the similar assumptions?)

Comment: @9877126, Not that I know of. `list`s let you store information of different types. (Actually, a `data.frame` is a special type of `list`.)